# Hammering out issues with simple calculators

Tags: javascript, html

Simply put, I am in a entry level computer science class, with the assignment based on fixing the html and javascript files below to create four separate working calculators. As far as I understand, however, I cannot find any formatting issues that prevent the two files from influencing each other, at least in terms of simple formatting.

```css
function ab()
{        //
    var a; 
    var b;  
    var r;  
    
    
    a = parsefloat(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
    b = parsefloat(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
    
    r = a + b;
    
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML= "The sum of the numbers is " + r;

}

function cd()
{        //
    var c; 
    var d;  
    var r2; 
    
    
    c = parsefloat(document.getElementById("txt3").value);
    d = parsefloat(document.getElementById("txt4").value);
    
    r2 = c - d;
    
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML= "The sum of the numbers is" + r2;

}

function ef()
{        //
    var e; 
    var f;  
    var r3; 
    
    
    c = parsefloat(document.getElementById("txt5").value);
    d = parsefloat(document.getElementById("txt6").value);
    
    r3 = e / f;
    
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML= "The sum of the numbers is" + r3;

}

function gh()
{        //
    var g; 
    var h;  
    var r4; 
    
    
    c = parsefloat(document.getElementById("txt7").value);
    d = parsefloat(document.getElementById("txt8").value);
    
    r4 = g * f;
    
    document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML= "The sum of the numbers is" + r4;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="convert.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<form>
<h1> Simple Addition</h1>


    Please type in two numbers to add them together:
    <input type="text" id="txt1" value="10"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" value="10"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id ="btn1" value="Add" onclick = "ab()" />
    <p id="p1"></p>

</form>
<h1> Simple Subtraction</h1>


    Please type in two numbers to subtract them
    <input type="text" id="txt3" value="10"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt4" value="10"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id ="btn2" value="Subtract" onclick = "cd()" />
    <p id="p2"></p>

<h1> Simple Division</h1>


    Please type in two numbers to divide them
    <input type="text" id="txt5" value="10"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt6" value="11"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id ="btn3" value="Divide" onclick = "ef()" />
    <p id="p3"></p>

<h1> Simple Multiplication</h1>


    Please type in two numbers to multiply them
    <input type="text" id="txt7" value="10"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt8" value="10"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id ="btn4" value="Multiply" onclick = "gh()" />
    <p id="p4"></p>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I started to go through it, and there's a substantial number of errors. Please ask a more specific question to get assistance. 

To provide you a starting off point, run the code snippet here, and you'll get clear error messages. For example, does parsefloat match the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat (capitalization is key).

Then, check the variables in each function. You re-use c and d, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your code that I changed in the snippet below.

- Moved javascript from css section
- Changed all instances of `parsefloat()` to `parseFloat()`
- Consistent spacing for string concatenation
- Correct variable names

The snippet below should yield the result that you were expecting.

```js
function ab() { //
  var a;
  var b;
  var r;


  a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
  b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt2").value);

  r = a + b;

  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "The sum of the numbers is " + r;

}

function cd() { //
  var c;
  var d;
  var r2;


  c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt3").value);
  d = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt4").value);

  r2 = c - d;

  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "The sum of the numbers is " + r2;

}

function ef() { //
  var e;
  var f;
  var r3;


  e = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt5").value);
  f = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt6").value);

  r3 = e / f;

  document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "The sum of the numbers is " + r3;

}

function gh() { //
  var g;
  var h;
  var r4;


  g = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt7").value);
  h = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt8").value);

  r4 = g * h;

  document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = "The product of the numbers is " + r4;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="convert.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
  <form>
    <h1> Simple Addition</h1>


    Please type in two numbers to add them together:
    <input type="text" id="txt1" value="10" />
    <input type="text" id="txt2" value="10" />
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Add" onclick="ab()" />
    <p id="p1"></p>

  </form>
  <h1> Simple Subtraction</h1>


  Please type in two numbers to subtract them
  <input type="text" id="txt3" value="10" />
  <input type="text" id="txt4" value="10" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="btn2" value="Subtract" onclick="cd()" />
  <p id="p2"></p>

  <h1> Simple Division</h1>


  Please type in two numbers to divide them
  <input type="text" id="txt5" value="10" />
  <input type="text" id="txt6" value="11" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="btn3" value="Divide" onclick="ef()" />
  <p id="p3"></p>

  <h1> Simple Multiplication</h1>


  Please type in two numbers to multiply them
  <input type="text" id="txt7" value="10" />
  <input type="text" id="txt8" value="10" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="btn4" value="Multiply" onclick="gh()" />
  <p id="p4"></p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parseFloat` instead of `parsefloat`
Also you don't need `<form>` tags in the form.

```css
function ab()
{        //
    var a; 
    var b;  
    var r;  
    
    
    a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
    b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
    
    r = a + b;
    
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML= "The sum of the numbers is " + r;

}

function cd()
{        //
    var c; 
    var d;  
    var r2; 
    
    
    c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt3").value);
    d = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt4").value);
    
    r2 = c - d;
    
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML= "The sum of the numbers is" + r2;

}

function ef()
{        //
    var e; 
    var f;  
    var r3; 
    
    
    c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt5").value);
    d = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt6").value);
    
    r3 = e / f;
    
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML= "The sum of the numbers is" + r3;

}

function gh()
{        //
    var g; 
    var h;  
    var r4; 
    
    
    c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt7").value);
    d = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt8").value);
    
    r4 = g * f;
    
    document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML= "The sum of the numbers is" + r4;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="convert.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<h1> Simple Addition</h1>


    Please type in two numbers to add them together:
    <input type="text" id="txt1" value="10"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" value="10"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id ="btn1" value="Add" onclick = "ab()" />
    <p id="p1"></p>

<h1> Simple Subtraction</h1>


    Please type in two numbers to subtract them
    <input type="text" id="txt3" value="10"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt4" value="10"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id ="btn2" value="Subtract" onclick = "cd()" />
    <p id="p2"></p>

<h1> Simple Division</h1>


    Please type in two numbers to divide them
    <input type="text" id="txt5" value="10"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt6" value="11"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id ="btn3" value="Divide" onclick = "ef()" />
    <p id="p3"></p>

<h1> Simple Multiplication</h1>


    Please type in two numbers to multiply them
    <input type="text" id="txt7" value="10"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt8" value="10"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id ="btn4" value="Multiply" onclick = "gh()" />
    <p id="p4"></p>

</body>

</html>
```